# from child1 modal to child 2 component Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

If I have this basic layout.
(child 2 has a modal in the page I want to click a button in the modal(located in child2) and have it carry the image(and value) to child1)

app==>
      Child1
      Child2 (modal) btn Onclick>(img)/btn> (/modal)

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a function in your app which takes the values when changed, passes the value to child 2 through props, and pass that function to child1 and use it in onClick of the button.

Answer (score 0):

I have come up with something like this. See whether its concepts fit your problem.

```
class Child1 extends React.Component{

    handleOnClick = () => {
        //your logic
    }

    render = () => (
        <Child2 handleOnClick={handleOnClick}/>
    )
}

class Child2 extends React.Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            value1: '',
            value2: '',
        }
    }

   extraLogicForOnClick = () => {
       const { handleOnClick } =  this.props;
       handleOnClick(this.state); 
   } 

    render = () => {
        <Modal>
            <Button onClick={extraLogicForOnClick}/>
        </Modal>
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Kowshhal's Answer is correct in that: The solution is to **pass a callback function** that **updates state** of the modal's open property (or however you're handling model content visibility) from the **Component** (i.e. parent) that contains the **ModalButton**/ModalContent.

However, due to **[React's Reconciliation](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html)** mechanism for rendering the DOM, this would be extremely inefficient and require re-rendering the entire application (**App**) if the callback and state of modal are located at "in your app." More importantly, such a brutal hacking of the DOM contradicts a core competency of React: Fast/Efficient DOM rendering.

If we choose to maintain state  and callback in application (as Kowshaal suggests) it would mean application would re-render every time the **modal** opens --- which means we needlessly re-render **Child1** just because **Child2** (modal) is changing **its** child (**ModalButon/ModalContent**).

**Where and How to Manage the open/closed modal state and callback:**

(1) Move **Child2** (modal) and of course its child (button) to be **Children** of **Child1 rather than App**. (2) Add callback and state to handle modal visibility in **Child1**.

This --crucially -- makes code more extensible say if you want to add **new Children** to **App** (siblings to **Child1**) down the road without having to re-render all of them whenever **Child1's** modal changes.

Want a **Navbar** at **App** Level down the road? A **Logo** component? Maybe a second **modal** that triggers different content? Easy --- no matter what's added --- only **Child1** will be hacked off thereby saving innocent DOM nodes.